# emacs: C major mode: how to get Tab key to insert tab (\t) always?

Tags: emacs

How to set Emacs to use \t for tabs, when C major-mode is active, and cursor is at any position - including line beginnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind it to `self-insert-command` in the keymap for C mode:

```
(define-key c-mode-base-map "\t" 'self-insert-command)
```

Comment: ..within a function which is called by hook at c-initialization-hook.